# Ensuring data consistency in a PointsAlongCircle object

Tags: python, object-oriented, comparative-review, coordinate-system

I'd like to write classes which are Pythonic, readable and easy-usable. A main issue for me is to keep data consistency. Here is an example *(version 1)*:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import math

Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])


class PointsAlongCircle(object):
    '''Set of regularly spaced points along a circle'''

    def __init__(self, center, radius, numpoints):
        '''
        center -- center of the circle (Point)
        radius -- radius of the circle (float)
        numpoints -- number of points along the circle

        >>> pts = PointsAlongCircle(Point(0, 0), 3, 4)
        >>> pts.points
        '''
        self.center = center
        self.radius = radius
        self.numpoints = numpoints

        center_x, center_y = self.center

        angles = [i * 2 * math.pi / numpoints for i in range(numpoints)]
        self.points = [Point(center_x + radius*math.cos(angle), center_y + radius*math.sin(angle)) for angle in angles]

pts = PointsAlongCircle(center=Point(0, 0), radius=3, numpoints=4)
print(pts.points)
```

This code displays as expected

```
[
    Point(x=3.0, y=0.0), 
    Point(x=1.8369701987210297e-16, y=3.0), 
    Point(x=-3.0, y=3.6739403974420594e-16), 
    Point(x=-5.51091059616309e-16, y=-3.0)
]
```

This code works. But in Python, public attributes are meant to be played around, right? So someone might legitimately try `pts.center = Point(1, 2)` and expect that `pts.points` will be updated to be centered around this new point, which is in reality not the case. And data consistency in the object is broken: the actual center of `pts.points` is not anymore `pts.center`.

Also in Python, there is duck-typing. Well, another developer might pass do something like this:

```
 center = [0, 0]
 pts = PointsAlongCircle(center=center, radius=3, numpoints=4) # so far so good
 center[0] = 1. # breaks data consistency in pts
```

The last line has a side effect: `pts.center` is updated, and it also breaks the consistency in `pts`.

Here is a second version of the class `PointsAlongCircle` which corrects these issues *(version 2)*:

```
class PointsAlongCircle(object):
    '''Set of regularly spaced points along a circle'''

    def __init__(self, center, radius, numpoints):
        '''
        center -- center of the circle (Point)
        radius -- radius of the circle (float)
        numpoints -- number of points along the circle

        >>> pts = PointsAlongCircle(Point(0, 0), 3, 4)
        >>> pts.points
        '''
        # remark: convert the input in immutable types
        self._center = Point(x=float(center[0]), y=float(center[1]))
        self._radius = radius
        if isinstance(numpoints, int):
            self._numpoints = int(numpoints)
        else:
            raise ValueError('numpoints must be an integer')

        center_x, center_y = self.center

        angles = [i * 2 * math.pi / numpoints for i in range(numpoints)]
        self._points = [Point(center_x + radius*math.cos(angle), center_y + radius*math.sin(angle)) for angle in angles]

    # Read-only attributes
    @property
    def center(self):
        return self._center

    @property
    def numpoints(self):
        return self._numpoints

    @property
    def radius(self):
        return self._radius

    @property
    def points(self):
        return tuple(self._points)  # return immutable to prevent any mess
```

I used properties to simulate read-only attributes, thus `pts.center = something` will raise an exception. And by converting the argument `center` in an immutable Point, I prevent any other modification of `pts.center`. Someone can still directly modify `pts._center`, but it is not my business anymore (consenting adults do not play with private attributes).

Same for `pts.points`: I return an immutable object to prevent things like this:

```
 points = pts.points
 points[0] = something
```

Here are now my questions:

1. Are my assumptions correct?
2. Version 2 of `PointsAlongCircle` seems more robust than version 1, but I am not convinced that it is better code. What do you think?
3. Is it acceptable to assume that every developer will read the documentation of the classes I write, and never try to change public attribute unless it is explicitly written that it is permitted? Or is it my job to lock attribute which are supposed to be read-only, even if I feel a bit like a control freak?
4. And what if I cannot always return read-only versions of the attributes, or if it costs too much resources?

A few last **remarks**:

- I do not pretend that using a class in this case is a very good choice, a function which returns a named tuple does the job. This code is meant to illustrate several questions I have.
- I also know that I can improve the code with magic methods (to have `len(pts)` instead of `pts.numpoints`). But this is not the main concern of this topic.
- I could also use properties to compute the attributes `center` and `numpoints` from `points` (example: `return len(self.points)`), instead of saving them. But let's assume we cannot due this because computing the attributes takes too much resources.

Comment: Why do you need `PointsAlongCircle` to be a class? Instead, you could make it a class method of `Point`, so you'd use `pts = Point.points_along_circle(center, 3, 4)` instead of `pts = PointsAlongCircle(center, 3, 4)`, and get a list instead of the custom object. Also, note that `'radium' != 'radius'`!

Comment: @jonrsharpe `Point.points_along_circle` would have been better, you are right. I meant to illustrate complex objects, where it is important to save all the parameters and the output (which possibly takes time to compute), in order for example to save/load them to/from file. Thanks for `radium != radius`.

Answer (score 3):

To address your questions:

> 1. Are my assumptions correct?

If you mean the assumption that *"public attributes are meant to be played around"*, then not necessarily. It's pretty well impossible to make things truly private in Python; just being public doesn't really mean *"do whatever you like"*, which brings me to:

> 3. Is it acceptable to assume that every developer will read the
>    documentation of the classes I write

No, but it *is* acceptable to assume that if they don't read the documentation, misuse your code and end up in trouble it's their fault and problem! You will often hear the expression *"we're all consenting adults here"* in Python - the language has lots of dynamic and introspective features, so we pretty much have to operate on the basis that nobody is particularly *trying* to do the wrong thing.

> 4. ...what if I cannot always return read-only versions of the attributes, or if it costs too much resources?

Then that's a trade-off you have to make and document. These issues come up a lot in software development; make the best decision you can at the time, write down why you made it and revisit it if a problem comes up later.

---

#### Alternative implementation

All that being said, you're right that if the user *can* change e.g. `center`, they will expect the `points` to be updated accordingly. A third way would be to use *caching*, trading off storage space against speed. Consider:

```
class PointsAlongCircle(object):

    _cache = {}  # we will store the sequences of Point objects here

    def __init__(self, center, radius, num_points):
        self.center = Point(*center)  # simpler way to deal with things!
        self.radius = radius
        self.num_points = num_points

    def points(self):
        """Get the points on the circle."""
        key = (self.center, self.radius, self.num_points)
        if key not in self._cache:
            self._cache[key] = self._calculate_points()
        return self._cache[key]

    def _calculate_points(self):
        """The actual calculations happen here, if the result isn't cached."""
        ...
```

For each combination of `center`, `radius` and `num_points`, the tuple of points is calculated only once.

---

#### A few more general review points

This seemed odd:

```
if isinstance(numpoints, int):  # if the input is an integer
    self._numpoints = int(numpoints)  # convert it to an integer
else:  # otherwise
    raise ValueError('numpoints must be an integer')  # complain about the 'value'?
```

As an alternative, if you *do* want to do duck-type checking:

```
try:
    self._numpoints = int(numpoints)
except ValueError:
    raise TypeError("can't convert {!r} to integer".format(numpoints))
```

However, note that this will convert `float` arguments, when the correct behaviour might be to raise an error. Another alternative is to wait for the error to come from `range`, although if you're using the above method that might be too late!

```
return tuple(self._points)
```

This also seemed odd - why not just make `self._points` a `tuple` to start with? This will be more efficient, as the current method creates a new object every time the property is called.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I should more rely on the documentation to describe what is permited and what is not. I don't really need the alternative implementation in my case: I'd rather have `center`, `numpoints` or `radius` always constant in an instance. About the int thing, I wanted to raise an error if there is a float, and ensure I save an int and not other types which look like int, numpy.int for example. And yes, self._points should be a tuple.